# Taylor offered him 500 dollars to do the work

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Taylor offered him 500 dollars to do the work.

Who does the work? Taylor or him?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think you know the answer; but I dont know.

Comment: Common sense tells us that it is normally the person who does a piece of work who is offered money for it. Taylor is unlikely to pay $500 for the chance to do some work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the sentence is ambiguous. It is **possible** (although unusual) that Taylor offered the unnamed "him" payment for a chance to do the work, possibly in hopes of gaining reputation. The famous literary episode of Tom Sawyer convincing other children to pay him (Sawyer) for the chance to whitewash a fence is an example.

But the far more likely interpretation is that Taylor was attempting to hire the unnamed person to do the work, and that Taylor was to pay "him" for this work. That is how a fluent speaker would read this sentence, in the absence of context making some other meaning clear.

Comment: Does the word 'offered' mean 'promised to pay' or 'paid'?

Comment: @BEBYGONES
 Most often neither. An offer is a **conditional** promise. If one says "I will pay you X if you do Y" that is an offer. **If** the offer is accepted that creates a contract, an exchange of promises.  But since this is in the past ("offered") it is possible that the contract has already been created and carried out, and payment made. But the word "offer" does not imply that payment has already been made, nor that a binding promise has already been given. An offer is a proposal, a suggestion. It may be accepted or declined, or a counter offer, a modified proposal given in return.

Comment: {Taylor to Jones}: "I'll pay you $500 to repair that deck" (*offer*) {Jones  to Taylor}: "I'll do it for $750" (*counter-offer*} {Taylor to Jones}: "Okay, that's a deal" (*acceptance*) Only after the acceptance is there a promise, a contract. At that point Jones has promised to do the work, and Taylor has promised to pay Jones. Neither has yet carried out the promise. That is a l;assic case of offer, counter offer, and acceptance, and I think  it helps make clear what "offer" means in such contexts.